# How to use log4j in the way/format I want?

Tags: java, logging, log4j

I want to understand how log4j works.
I've read a lot of tutorials and all the answers from this site, but I still didn't get a concrete example which works.

I've tried this:

```
import org.apache.log4j.*;

public class Exercise {
    private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(SimpleLogger.class);

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        BasicConfigurator.configure();

        // ConsoleAppender myAppender = new ConsoleAppender(null, "System.out");
        // myAppender.setLayout(new SimpleLayout());
        // logger.addAppender(myAppender);

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            logger.info("You are here!");
        }

        logger.info("End of program");
    }
}
```

With this class:

```
import org.apache.log4j.spi.LoggingEvent;

public class SimpleLogger extends org.apache.log4j.Layout {

    @Override
    public void activateOptions() {

    }

    @Override
    public String format(LoggingEvent event) {
        return "log message = " + event.getMessage().toString() + "/n";
    }

    @Override
    public boolean ignoresThrowable() {
        return true;
    }
}
```

But my output is:

```
0 [main] INFO SimpleLogger  - You are here!
1 [main] INFO SimpleLogger  - You are here!
1 [main] INFO SimpleLogger  - You are here!
1 [main] INFO SimpleLogger  - You are here!
1 [main] INFO SimpleLogger  - You are here!
1 [main] INFO SimpleLogger  - End of program
```

I've tried also, with the code not commented but all I got is the output in double form or something.

Question:
How can I make the output (Console or File) be in the format that I want?
Do I need to modify an external file like (log4j.properties)?

Comment: yes you have to modify log4j.properies to get formatted output

Comment: Yes you do need to modify log4j.properties and google more!

Comment: here you go check this manual http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/manual.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line:

```
private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(SimpleLogger.class);
```

simply informs the default logger that the current context for logging is SimpleLogger.  It does NOT specify the underlying logger implementation.  In fact you do not need to implement a custom logger at all.  You simply need to use a configurator that allows you to specify a format in your config file.  A common technique is to use the XmlConfigurator, then your XML config file can be quite specific as to formatting under various contexts.  Look [here](http://wiki.apache.org/logging-log4j/Log4jXmlFormat) for details on XML-based configuration.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I've used PropertyConfigurator.configure(CONFIG_FILE) where CONFIG_FILE is the address of my properties file.

Answer (score 0):

Having log4j configuration in a property file is a best practice.
By specifying `ConversionPattern` you can get the desired output format. For example

```
log4j.appender.rollingFile.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ABSOLUTE} %5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
```

Comment: log4j.property file should be in your classpath. You can put it in your src folder.

Answer (score 0):

the line:

```
private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(SimpleLogger.class);
```

does not mean that now the logger will use your class to log, it just mean it will look in the log4j.properties file for a logger called `SimpleLogger` (or if it is in a package it will look for `some.package.SimpleLogger` ) and it will use the pattern layout defined for that logger.

If it can't find that logger it will default to the root logger and use the pattern layout of the root logger appender.